# pyautogui.write not recognizing \t as tab presses

Tags: python, openpyxl, pyautogui, python-3.9

#### Goal:

I'm trying to read a product number (such as A11841-2 -  -) from an Excel cell  using `openpyxl` and write it into a field in a database window using `pyautogui.write`. My original code (https://pastebin.com/6EUFQ09s):

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('repack_locns.xlsx')
sheet = wb['r_locn']
sku = sheet.cell(row=2, column=1).value
 
#5 Enter product code into PKMS (cursor should already be where it's supposed to be)
    #and press Enter
import pyautogui
pyautogui.write(sku)
```

did not write the information into the correct fields (the number 2 after the first hyphen in product code A11841-2 -  - should be in the suffix field, not in the style field as is pictured in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ez4s.png)). [Note: I'm using Mu 1.1.0.alpha.2 to write my code in and run it from]

#### What I did:

I started by finding and replacing the hyphens in the product numbers with `\t` within Excel, resulting in product codes like this: `A11841\t2 \t  \t`. When I simply copy the product number from the excel cell and paste it into the code (modification is on line 34 at https://pastebin.com/sX1SdV8Q):

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('repack_locns.xlsx')
sheet = wb['r_locn']
sku = 'A11841\t2 \t  \t'
 
#5 Enter product code into PKMS (cursor should already be where it's supposed to be)
    #and press Enter
import pyautogui
pyautogui.write(sku)
```

and put a single quote on each end, it works! It reads the `\t` as tab presses and enters the product code into the correct fields ([2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xveyZ.png)). I then used my original code to read from a copy of the original Excel file that had this formatting change.

#### The problem:

When the product number is written by `pyautogui`, it’s not recognizing the `\t` as tab presses. Instead, it’s just writing them as characters ([3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVbYf.png)).

#### What I’ve tried:

I used `pyperclip` to try and include that copy/paste step in my code, so I could eventually make it repeatable. I used `openpyxl` to pull from the Excel cell and then concatenated single quotes on each end. However, it didn’t work; the same issue arose where the `pyautogui.write` function doesn’t recognize the `\t` as tab presses and simply writes them as characters.

I used `type()` and both what is written by `pyautogui.write` and what I copy/paste directly from Excel (and then enclose with single quotes) are classified as strings. Not sure why the `\t` are not being treated the same in each case.

Answer (score 0):

LESSON LEARNED: CHECK OUTPUT LINE BY LINE IN YOUR PROGRAM WHEN YOU'RE HAVING PROBLEMS

It was simple, but I'm a new programmer so I didn't catch it nearly as quickly as I could have lol

```
sheet.cell(row=2, column=1).value
```

Turns out that piece of code spits out `'A11841\\t2 \\t  \\t'` not `'A11841\t2 \t  \t'`. Makes total sense, since it's reading the text `A11841\t2 \t  \t` from an Excel cell. I simply used `join()` and `split()` and then `pyautogui.write()` and it worked!:

```
sku = sheet.cell(row=2, column=1).value
sku_='\t'.join(sku.split('\\t'))
pyautogui.write(sku_)
```

As you can see in [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjSUJ.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjSUJ.png), pyautogui.write() correctly interpreted `\t` as a tab press.